# Rails how to get SoundCloud track information using SoundCloud song URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soundcloud

In my rails project, I want to get SoundCloud track/song title, description, provider data using song url given by user from his SoundCloud account or any SoundCloud link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SoundCloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) for this - see section [SoundCloud URLs](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#resolving):

> If you have a permalink URL to a particular resource, but need more information such as an ID or other property. In these cases, you can use the [/resolve](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) endpoint to extract a full representation of the resource.

There's also an example using *Ruby*:

```
require 'soundcloud'

# create client with your app's credentials
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID')

# a permalink to a track
track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/voca-nomen-tuum'

# resolve track URL into track resource
track = client.get('/resolve', :url => track_url)

# now that we have the track id, we can get a list of comments, for example
client.get("/tracks/#{track.id}/comments").each do |comment|
  puts "Someone said: #{comment.body} at #{comment.timestamp}"
end
```

Comment: I have only track_url, no client_id.I am trying to retrieve like:
client = SoundCloud.new(:access_token => my_access_token)
    track = client.get('/resolve', :url => link)
    raise track.inspect
and the error is: HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: You get your own `client_id`, with which you can use the API. You have to "*register a new app*", which is linked on the API documentation right side menu. If you have retrieved an valid `:access_token` from `client.exchange_token` it may be sufficient.